# How to Prevent user to change our form action attribute?

Tags: php, html

I created Login system recently, But I have some problem with my code.When Inspect element in Chrome and change the form action to another PHP process page, It's worked! and I don't want user to do that.
Can everyone give me a technique to validate the form without getting change?
sorry my english!
Hope you understand my problem!

```
<form class="container mt-5 bg-light p-5 rounded" action="process/login.process.php" method="post">
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: <form class="container mt-5 bg-light p-5 rounded" action="process/login.process.php" method="post">

Comment: example, user wants to change the action=".." to another my php file. I just don't want user to do that!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow and unfortunately that is impossible to lock client-side activity, and this is would not affect anything that may harm your websites caused by that action.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a login system, maybe you should set a session var for user.

For example (this is only a sample code, ignoring security issues and design patterns):

**form.html**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['username'] != 'root') {
    header('Location: /form.html');
    exit(1);
}
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
header('Location: /logged.php');
?>
```

**logged.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
    header('Location: /form.html');
    exit(1);
}
// write your code from here

?>
```

So, in every page you want to keep private (accessible only for logged in users), you must check if that session var is valid. Otherwise, you should redirect user to login page.

Doing this or not, you can't block user to handle anything in client side. That's why we must check all user input in server side: security! ;-)